# PowerShell fails to pick correct ParameterSet based on number of positional parameters

Tags: powershell, parameter-sets, powershell-7

I am attempting to write a PowerShell function `Set-MyRef` which uses ParameterSets to expose its available parameters. I would like the function to have parameter sets similar to:

```
Set-MyRef -Latest

Set-MyRef -LocalBranch

Set-MyRef [-Tag] <string>

Set-MyRef [-Env] <string> -LocalBranch

Set-MyRef [-Env] <string> -Latest

Set-MyRef [-Env] <string> [-Tag] <string>
```

That is, exactly one of the options `-Latest`, `-LocalBranch` or `-Tag` may be given, with an optional `-Env` as first positional parameter.
Importantly, I would expect `Set-MyRef 'foo'` to be parsed as `-Tag 'foo'`, and `Set-MyRef 'foo' 'bar'` to be parsed as `-Env 'foo' -Tag 'bar'`.

I attempted to implement it using ParameterSets:

```
function Set-MyRef {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'EnvTag')]
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLatest')]
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLocal')]
        [string]$Env,
        [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Tag')]
        [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'EnvTag')]
        [string]$Tag,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Latest')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLatest')]
        [switch]$Latest,
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Local')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLocal')]
        [switch]$LocalBranch
    )

    Write-Host "{ Env: $Env, Tag: $Tag, Latest: $Latest, LocalBranch: $LocalBranch }"
}
```

Which gives the correct parsed syntax:

```
$ Get-Command Set-MyRef -Syntax

Set-MyRef [-Env] <string> -LocalBranch [<CommonParameters>]

Set-MyRef [-Env] <string> -Latest [<CommonParameters>]

Set-MyRef [-Env] <string> [-Tag] <string> [<CommonParameters>]

Set-MyRef [-Tag] <string> [<CommonParameters>]

Set-MyRef -Latest [<CommonParameters>]

Set-MyRef -LocalBranch [<CommonParameters>]
```

But fails to correctly parse the parameters. When calling it using only one position parameter it uses it for both `$Env` and `$Tag`:

```
$ Set-MyRef 'foo' # incorrect - expect Env = $null, Tag = 'foo'
{ Env: foo, Tag: foo, Latest: False, LocalBranch: False }
$ Set-MyRef -Tag 'foo' # correct
{ Env: , Tag: foo, Latest: False, LocalBranch: False }
```

How do I change my ParameterSet specification so PowerShell can correctly pick the `Set-MyRef [Tag] <string>` ParameterSet, when only one positional parameter is given?

Comment: What you're expecting is simply not possible with positional arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**It looks like you've run into a *bug***, where a single positional argument is mistakenly bound to *both* `-Tag` and `-Env`, seemingly due to both having a `Position=0` parameter-attribute property, despite those properties belonging to *different parameter sets*.

- Note: While your scenario is *unusual* in that what parameter the first positional argument should bind to to *depends on the target parameter set*, it is *logically unequivocal*, and the de-facto behavior doesn't make sense - see [GitHub issue #20405](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20405).

---

**Workarounds**:

- *Preferably*, change the order of the positional parameters to **bind `-Tag` first, before `-Env`**:

```bash
function Set-MyRef {
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Tag')]
  param (
      [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvTag')]
      [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLatest')]
      [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLocal')]
      [string]$Env,
      [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Tag')]
      [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvTag')]
      [string]$Tag,
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Latest')]
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLatest')]
      [switch]$Latest,
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Local')]
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLocal')]
      [switch]$LocalBranch
  )

  Write-Host "{ Env: $Env, Tag: $Tag, Latest: $Latest, LocalBranch: $LocalBranch }"
}
```

- Otherwise, the workaround gets cumbersome:

```bash
function Set-MyRef {
  [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Env')]
  param (
      [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvTag')]
      [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLatest')]
      [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLocal')]
      [string]$Env,
      [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Tag')]
      [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = $false, ParameterSetName = 'EnvTag')]
      [string]$Tag,
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Latest')]
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLatest')]
      [switch]$Latest,
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'Local')]
      [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'EnvLocal')]
      [switch]$LocalBranch
  )

  # Compensate for the broken parameter binding, by inferring
  # from the fact that the -Tag argument is the same as the -Env argument
  # that only *one* positional argument was passed and that it was meant to
  # bind to -Tag.
  if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'EnvTag' -and $Env -eq $Tag) {
    $Env = $null
  }
  Write-Host "{ Env: $Env, Tag: $Tag, Latest: $Latest, LocalBranch: $LocalBranch }"
}
```

- Note:

  - The above assumes that there's no *legitimate* use case where the `-Env` and `-Target` arguments happen to have the *same value*.  With substantially more effort, the latter case could be handled too.

Comment: While this fixes the single-parameter case, it unfortunately looks like it swaps the `-Tag`/`-Env` parameters in the double-parameter case: `Set-MyRef 'foo' 'bar'` should be parsed as `-Env 'foo' -Tag 'bar'`, but gets parsed as `-Env 'bar' -Tag 'foo'.

Comment: I'm assuming negative `Position` is undefined behavior, since I can't find it in any documentation (and it causes an error when running `Get-Command Set-MyRef -Syntax`). It's a neat trick though!

Comment: Good points, @JHR; I've updated the answer to note that the suggested workaround isn't one. I'll think about this some more.

Comment: @JHR, please see if my update helps.

Comment: Thanks @mklement0, your second workaround ended up being what I went with. I also really appreciate the acknowledgement that the ParameterSets are unambiguous, and the behaviour ideally should be supported - I was starting to pull my hair out wondering if I was in the wrong. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it, @JHR; my pleasure. I've created [GitHub issue #20405](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20405) to discuss the unexpected behavior.